# How to know which Linux kernel versions Qt 4.7 supports

Tags: linux, qt

I'd like to develop Qt 4.7 based applications running on my arm-linux MCU.
However, I'm not sure if this Qt 4.7 supports the following two things:

1. my Linux 2.6.37 kernel
2. my Ti3530-cortexA8 MCU.

I know it's hard to get a conclusion here so I'd like to know where I can find such references.

Comment: Kernel versions don’t really matter most of the time.  Qt usually talks to the X server instead.

Comment: @Kwpolska For example. If QT want to display something, it will talk to the X server. However, the X server also need to talk to the Linux kernel to actually perform the displaying. So Linux kernel version does matter, does not it?

Comment: Not for Qt, but for Xorg.  That’s two different things.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with [this query on the Qt website](http://qt-project.org/search?search=supported%20architectures). The first link goes to the 4.8 documentation but you can go to that page and change the URL so that it goes to 4.7 to see the supported platforms/architectures that Qt supports.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/supported-platforms.html

I would do additional searches on the qt-project.org website to see how well that particular CPU is supported.